# com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to my class

Tags: java, json, casting, gson

I have some problems with getting my object from a JSON string.

I got the class `Product`

```
public class Product {
    private String mBarcode;
    private String mName;
    private String mPrice;

    public Product(String barcode, String name, String price) {
        mBarcode = barcode;
        mName = name;
        mPrice = price;
    }

    public int getBarcode() {
        return Integer.parseInt(mBarcode);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return Double.parseDouble(mPrice);
    }
}
```

From my server I get an `ArrayList<Product>` in JSON String representation. For example:

```
[{"mBarcode":"123","mName":"Apfel","mPrice":"2.7"},
{"mBarcode":"456","mName":"Pfirsich","mPrice":"1.1111"},
{"mBarcode":"89325982","mName":"Birne","mPrice":"1.5555"}]
```

This String is generated like this:

```
public static <T> String arrayToString(ArrayList<T> list) {
    Gson g = new Gson();
    return g.toJson(list);
}
```

To get my Object back I use this function:

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> stringToArray(String s) {
    Gson g = new Gson();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<T>>(){}.getType();
    ArrayList<T> list = g.fromJson(s, listType);
    return list;
}
```

But when calling

```
String name = Util.stringToArray(message).get(i).getName();
```

I get the error 
*com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to object.Product*

What am I doing wrong? It looks like it created a List of LinkedTreeMaps but how do i convert those into my Product Object?

Comment: Try this https://www.freakyjolly.com/com-google-gson-internal-linkedtreemap-cannot-be-cast-to-how-to-resolve/

Comment: Try  this -keepattributes Signature

Comment: You can iterate through the `ArrayList` to convert each `LinkedTreeMap` item to a `Product` item. You can use `Gson` a second time to do the conversion. See example code here: https://randomgyan.com/mapping-linkedtreemap-response-to-class-using-gson-utility/

Answer (score 112):

Due to type erasure, the parser can't fetch the real type T at runtime. One workaround would be to provide the class type as parameter to the method.

Something like this works, there are certainly other possible workarounds but I find this one very clear and concise.

```
public static <T> List<T> stringToArray(String s, Class<T[]> clazz) {
    T[] arr = new Gson().fromJson(s, clazz);
    return Arrays.asList(arr); //or return Arrays.asList(new Gson().fromJson(s, clazz)); for a one-liner
}
```

And call it like:

```
String name = stringToArray(message, Product[].class).get(0).getName();
```

Comment: This answer provides a workaround, but does not address the problem of nested generics. See these two answers for a more general solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14506181/4745878
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26203635/4745878

Comment: @AljoschaMeyer +1 for the useful links.

Comment: If you are trying to use GSON + Room, that solution will not work, because Room doesn't allow generic field type. This works https://stackoverflow.com/a/52224425/6009482

Answer (score 28):

Similar to Alexis C's answers. but in Kotlin.
Just pass the class type into function and clarify what generic type is.
Here is simplified example.

```
inline fun <reified T> parseArray(json: String, typeToken: Type): T {
    val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
    return gson.fromJson<T>(json, typeToken)
}
```

Here is example call

```
fun test() {
    val json: String = "......."
    val type = object : TypeToken<List<MyObject>>() {}.type
    val result: List<MyObject> = parseArray<List<MyObject>>(json = json, typeToken = type)
    println(result)
}
```

Comment: *inline* function with *reified* type argument resolved the problem

Comment: that's a great solution

Answer (score 24):

I also had problems with GSON complaining about casting LinkedTreeMaps.

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27271365/2128921) provided by Alexis and the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14506181/2128921) by Aljoscha explains why the error occurs; "Generics on a type are typically erased at runtime." My issue was that my code worked when I ran it normally, but using ProGuard caused code to be stripped that was vital to casting.

You can follow Alexis's answer and more clearly define the cast and that should fix the problems. You can also add the ProGuard [rules](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg) given by Google (simply doing this cleared the issue up for me).

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

Moral of the Story: Always check to see what ProGuard rules you need.

Comment: I had to define my custom base response abstract class to keep.
`-keep class * extends in.krsh.app.webservice.BaseResponseBody`. The class is as like `internal abstract class BaseResponseBody<DataType> { }`.

Comment: nice, save my day!

Answer (score 14):

If you use your own `ArrayList<MyObject>` in gson when parsing;

```
Type typeMyType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyObject>>(){}.getType();

ArrayList<MyObject> myObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString, typeMyType)
```

Answer (score 3):

I also faced class cast exception of com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap for my signed build only. I added these below lines in progurard. Then it works fine.

```
-keepattributes Signature

-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep class com.google.** { *; }

-keep class sun.misc.** { *; }
```

Comment: Please add more information and explain the solution.

Comment: You can add this in your proguard and will work fine with signed build

Comment: Those are extremely broad Proguard rules. Rules that keep huge swathes of code defeat the purpose of Proguard, since it cannot strip out the unused code in those packages which is the entire reason you are using Proguard. The keep statements should go all the way down to just the specific class you need, rather than keeping all of com.google.** and sun.misc.**. The correct rule is something like "-keep class com.google.api.services.vision.v1.model.BatchAnnotateImagesResponse { <fields>; }", depending where the GSON model class you are using is stored.

Answer (score 3):

For **JSON**

```
{
    results: [
    {
        id: "10",
        phone: "+91783XXXX345",
        name: "Mr Example",
        email: "freaky@jolly.com"
    },
    {
        id: "11",
        phone: "+9178XXXX66",
        name: "Mr Foo",
        email: "freaky@jolly.com"
    }],
    statusCode: "1",
    count: "2"
}
```

In **listView BaseAdapter file** we need to map data using LinkedTreeMap Key Value object to get row attribute value as below:

```
...
...

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if(view==null)
        {
            view= LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.listview_manage_clients,viewGroup,false);
        }

        TextView mUserName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        TextView mUserPhone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userPhone);


        Object getrow = this.users.get(i);
        LinkedTreeMap<Object,Object> t = (LinkedTreeMap) getrow;
        String name = t.get("name").toString();

        mUserName.setText("Name is "+name);
        mUserPhone.setText("Phone is "+phone);

        return view;
    }
...
...
```

[ListView from JSON Data using Retrofit2 in Android Example](https://www.freakyjolly.com/create-multiple-columns-listview-from-json-data-using-retrofit2-in-android-example/)

[Source Link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/com-google-gson-internal-linkedtreemap-cannot-be-cast-to-how-to-resolve/)

Comment: Thanks ,solved my problem.My Kotlin code:                    val t: LinkedTreeMap<*, *> = scoreValueEntity as LinkedTreeMap<*, *>
                    t["value"]?.toString()?.toFloat() ?: 0f

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I noticed it only occures when you have List as argument.

My solution is to wrap the list in another Object:

```
class YourObjectList {

    private List<YourObject> items;

    // constructor, getter and setter
}
```

With that single object, i had no more problems with class cast exception.

Comment: This is the easiest and most correct solution. Serializing and Deserializing a naked list of objects causes problems but if you wrap a plain java bean around the list, everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

use this when parsing

```
  public static <T> List<T> parseGsonArray(String json, Class<T[]> model) {
    return Arrays.asList(new Gson().fromJson(json, model));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{"root": 
 [
  {"mBarcode":"123","mName":"Apfel","mPrice":"2.7"},
  {"mBarcode":"456","mName":"Pfirsich","mPrice":"1.1111"},
  {"mBarcode":"89325982","mName":"Birne","mPrice":"1.5555"}
 ]
} 


JsonObject root = g.fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
//read root element which contains list
JsonElement e = root.get("root");
//as the element is array convert it 
JsonArray ja  = e.getAsJsonArray();

for(JsonElement j : ja){
   //here use the json to parse into your custom object 
}
```

Comment: Please include an explanation and possible solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answers already mentioned here, if you have a generic class that handles, say, HTTP calls, it maybe useful to pass `Class<T>` as part of the constructor.

To give a little more detail, this happens because Java cannot infer the `Class<T>` during runtime with just `T`. It needs the actual solid class to make the determination.

So, if you have something like this, like I do:

```
class HttpEndpoint<T> implements IEndpoint<T>
```

you can allow the inheriting code to also send the `class<T>`, since at that point is it clear what T is.

```
public HttpEndpoint(String baseurl, String route, Class<T> cls) {
    this.baseurl = baseurl;
    this.route = route;
    this.cls = cls;
}
```

inheriting class:

```
public class Players extends HttpEndpoint<Player> {

    public Players() {
        super("http://127.0.0.1:8080", "/players",  Player.class);
    }
}
```

while not entirely a clean solution, it does keep the code packaged up and you don't have to `Class<T>` between methods.