# Android ClassCastException only in release build

Tags: java, android, for-loop, classcastexception

I have a simple code for get the nicknames from the recipient's list in my Android app:

```
public void addItemsToSpinner(List<Recipient> list) {
    List<String> nicks = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Recipient recipient: list) {
        nicks.add(recipient.getNickname());
    }
}
```

It works fine when I try it debug mode, but if I release through Crashlytics Beta, it always crashes. Actually the error is this:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: dbu cannot be cast to lh

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: What is dbu? What is lh?

Comment: I guess you are using Proguard or something to obfuscate the code, check the mapping to see what classes they are originally.

Comment: You are right! lh is Recipient and dbu is com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap. I forgot to add the Recipient model class to proguard rules, but I still get error and I don't get why gson is  involved.

Comment: Maybe check if LinkedTreeMap requires special rules for Proguard too, nearly every library or plugin needs some modification.

Comment: Yes I know that, I found some rules, but unfortunately nothing changed, except now I can see the class names in the log.

Comment: So the error now is: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.mypackage.model.Recipient

Comment: Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27253555/com-google-gson-internal-linkedtreemap-cannot-be-cast-to-my-class